# Recursive CTE - Update Costs from Bottom to Top - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, recursion

Application:  This is a Bill of Materials system where the children ingredient costs (or Work in Progress) are multiplied by a Parent use factor for each child.

Goal: Updating costs on table tblITEM, using Parent/Child and UseRate from table tblLINK using a bottom to top recursion.  The tblITEM has types of records (C=Raw Material, P=Work In Progress, N=Finished Good).

Status: It was successfully updating one row at a time, but it required running the stored procedure 22 times (the full explosion level).  And after messing with it that's even broke.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated, I have a cursory knowledge of tsql.

Environment: It will run on SQL Server 2012 as a stored procedure that I'm calling from Access 2013.

EDITS:  Updated code comments and provided visual display of expected updates.

**End Here**

```
Parent 219558   <== Update Item record with Sum Of Factored Consumes ($11,790.00) 
--------------
Consumes    218158  @ UseRate  2.0  * Cost  $5,895.00  =  $11,790.00           


Parent 218158   <== Update Item record with Sum Of Factored Consumes ($5,895.00) 
--------------
Consumes    219358  @ UseRate  2.5  * Cost  $2,358.00  =  $ 5,895.00


Parent 219358   <== Update Item record with Sum Of Factored Consumes ($2,358.00) 
--------------
Consumes    115132  @ UseRate  3.0  * Cost  $  786.00  =  $ 2,358.00    


Parent 115132   <== Update Item record with Sum Of Factored Consumes ($786.00) 
--------------
Consumes    110506  @ UseRate  1.5  * Cost  $  524.00  =  $   786.00


Parent 110506   <== Update Item record with Sum Of Factored Consumes ($524.00)
--------------
Consumes    109     @ UseRate  0.5  * Cost  $1,000.00  =  $   500.00
Consumes    4173    @ UseRate  2.0  * Cost  $    6.00  =  $    12.00
Consumes    4803    @ UseRate  2.0  * Cost  $    6.00  =  $    12.00
```

**Begin here**

Going up through the tree, summing factored results and updating the parent record on tblITEM

What occurs is that 109 at the bottom gets a price increase and I want to ripple the cost up through the parents and update the table tblITEM.

```
USE [BOM_LINK_TEST]
GO


-- Drop tables if they already exist
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblITEM', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.tblITEM;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblLINK', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.tblLINK;


  -------------------  BEGIN DDLs -------------------------
  ---------------------------------------------------------

--Create tblITEM Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblITEM](
    [ItemID] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ItemType] char(1) NOT NULL,
    [RMCost] [numeric](18,6) NULL,
    [OHCost] [numeric](18,6) NULL,
    [TotalCost] [numeric](18,6) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblITEM] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ITEMID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


--Update tblITEM with Data
INSERT INTO tblITEM ( ItemID, ItemType, RMCost, OHCost, TotalCost ) 
VALUES 
     (109,    'C', 1000.00,  0.003501,  0.503501) 
    ,(110506, 'P',    2.50,  0.004206,  2.504206) 
    ,(115132, 'P',    4.58,  0.002409,  4.582409)
    ,(4803,   'C',    6.00,  0.004509,  9.582409)
    ,(219358, 'P',    9.45,  1.000504, 10.450504)
    ,(4173,   'C',    6.00,  0.004509,  9.582409) 
    ,(218158, 'P',   12.00, 1.450105, 13.450105) 
    ,(219558, 'N',   13.67, 1.004504, 14.674504)  
; 



--Create tblLINK Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLINK](
    [ParentItem] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ChildItem] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [UseFactor] [numeric](20, 6) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblLINK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParentItem] ASC,
    [ChildItem] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


--Update tblLINK with Data
INSERT INTO tblLINK( ParentItem, ChildItem, UseFactor ) 
VALUES 
     (110506, 109, 0.5000) 
    ,(110506, 4173, 2.0000) 
    ,(115132, 110506, 1.5000) 
    ,(219358, 115132, 3.0000)
    ,(110506, 4803, 2.0000)
    ,(218158, 219358, 2.5000) 
    ,(219558, 218158, 2.0000)  
; 




---***** THIS IS THE PORTION THAT DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY *****---
--  It performs the recursion, but does not recursively update

-------------------  Start ROLL-UP RECALC -----------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------

;With 

--Bottom-Up Anchor
    cteTREE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            p.ChildItem,
            p.ParentItem,
            p.UseFactor
        FROM tblLINK p

            UNION ALL

        SELECT
            c.ChildItem,
            c.ParentItem,
            c.UseFactor
        FROM tblLINK c

    -- Invert Join To Walk Up Tree
    INNER JOIN cteTREE p ON c.ChildItem = p.ParentItem  
    ),

--  Sum of Children 
    cSUM AS 
        (
        SELECT BL.ParentItem, 
            CAST(Sum(BI.RMCost * BL.UseFactor) AS numeric(18,6)) AS SumRMCost,      
            CAST(Sum(BI.OHCost * BL.UseFactor) AS numeric(18,6)) AS SumOHCost,
            CAST(Sum(BI.RMCost * BL.UseFactor) AS numeric(18,6)) +
            CAST(Sum(BI.OHCost * BL.UseFactor) AS numeric(18,6)) AS SumTotalCost
        FROM tblLINK as BL
        INNER JOIN tblITEM as BI 
        ON BL.ParentItem = BI.ItemID 
        GROUP BY ParentItem
        )

--********  This Update is where I have an issue ********** ----
-- The Update Statement was only updating one row at a time 
-- I believe a different join, output, rollup, level, hierarchyID
-- or temp table is needed to sum the children first
-- so that the update sequentially rolls all the way up the tree 


 --  Perform Table Updates With Summed Result Set
    UPDATE tblITEM 
    SET
        RMCost = cSUM.SumRMCost,
        OHCost = cSUM.SumOHCost,
        TotalCost = cSUM.SumTotalCost
    FROM cSUM
    INNER JOIN tblITEM AS tBI
    ON   cSUM.ParentItem = tBI.ItemID 



----------------------  Show Results -----------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT TOP 1000 [ItemID]
      ,[ItemType]
      ,[RMCost]
      ,[OHCost]
      ,[TotalCost]
  FROM [BOM_LINK_TEST].[dbo].[tblITEM]
```

Comment: It would likely help to post expected output, and please elaborate on what exactly is not working correctly -- that's a lot of code to read without knowing what to look for.

Comment: Did the edits help explain any better?  I'm doing a basic bottom up recursion.  And I want to take the sum of my bottoms and continually update their linked parents with a new price.  I have the recursion working, but I don't know how to keep running the sequential updates.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do.  Except, instead of summing salaries, I want to sum ingredient costs multiplied by the Usefactor.  
So I'm going to give the derived table (solution #4) a try.

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/calculate-sum-salaries-employee-tree

Comment: In the absence of any help I decided to stabilize the original stored proc to update one row at a time and do a For/Next loop from Access with VBA to run it multiple times.  I know this is possible from within tsql, but it's not clear to me how to loop through the update in tsql.